# Если введен пароль

Tags: ссылки, пароль

Одна строка, если в неё введен правильный пароль, перенаправить по ссылке

Comment: Что за строка? Вы имеете в виду поле ввода input?  
И что значит правильный пароль? Этот пароль проверяется на стороне клиента? Тогда это защита от блондинок, ибо любой может открыть код и скопировать нужную ссылку.

Comment: Мало информации. Поподробней пожалуйста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если мои телепатические способности меня не подводят, то алгоритм решения следующий:

1. Есть такое событие keyup. При вводе пароля в input-e срабатывает это событие
2. При каждом нажатии клавиши берем пароль и ajax-ом отправляем его на сервер и получаем ответ правильный пароль или нет
3. Если правильный, редиректим на нужную страницу с помощью location